# Get ListView index from point - C# (Windows 8.1 Store App)

Tags: c#, listview, drag-and-drop, windows-8.1

I have a simple drag/drop function working between two ListView elements, but I would like to be able to drop an object into the ListView according to the cursor position (rather than at the beginning or end). I already have managed to get this point as a PointerPoint from a pointer release event, but I can't figure out how to convert it to the correct index of the ListView.

Unfortunately `ListView.GetItemAt(X,Y).Index` does not exist for .NET for Windows 8.1 store apps (as far as I know). Is there any equivalent to this that I can use to get the index?

My code looks like this:

```
public PointerPoint PP { get; set; }

// Called when pointer released over ListView
private void PointerRelease(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView lv = (ListView)sender;
        PP = e.GetCurrentPoint(lv);
    }

// Called when object dropped onto ListView
private void ListViewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
            ListView dropListView = sender as ListView;
            int index = dropListView.GetItemAt(PP.Position.X, PP.Position.Y).Index;
            // Do drag/drop code
    }
```